# What have increased technically on Magento 2 Enterprise?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, comparison

I saw something new on CLI and the Reward Module.

What are the things that improved in Magento Enterprise Edition?

Is there something technically different about 2.0 EE and 2.1 EE?

Thanks